# SCALA + WEB : how to write some xml to a file

Tags: xml, scala, spray

I created a scala project which uses the web framework SPRAY.

I would like to store some xml stuff to a file; do you know how I can write this, knowing you should be careful with absolute & relative paths?

I tried this:

```
val url = getClass.getResource(fileString)
val newFile = new File(url.toURI().getPath())
val fop = new FileOutputStream(newFile)
val content = xml.getBytes()
fop.write(content)
```

but since the filestring matches to a non existent file, I get a NULL reference error at the second line(with getPath).

thanks!

Comment: What is the value of fileString? What's the null reference, url, or toURI, or getPath? getPath just does string manipulation so twhether the file exists or not is not relevant.

Comment: hello, fileString="../../classes/models/" + "test1.xml", it's a relative path, and the file does not yet exists : I want to create it. Do you know what are the right statements?

Comment: What is the value of url?

Comment: it's "null" : I must change of method but I don't know what to choose.

Comment: SO this question is really nothing about how to create files, but how to call getClass/getResource? Unfortunately, they're not things I'm familiar with. Maybe someone else can point out what's needed here.